# Expressing $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+2)k!}$ in terms of $n$.

Tags: summation, factorial

> How would I express $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+2)k!}$$ in terms of $n$?

An attempt of mine is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+2)k!} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(k+1)! + k!},$$ which is not useful for me. Is there any established expression for a sum involving factorials in terms of $n$?

An elementary approach is of the first priority, say high-school math.

Comment: I don't think your attempt is correct, you would need $2k!=k!$.

Comment: Yeah, such a problem may require some luck to see the key ingredient if there is no established expression for a sum involving factorials.

Comment: Thanks. I should have stated in the question that no "advanced" math. can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{(k+2)k!} = \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} = \frac{1}{(k+1)!} - \frac{1}{(k+2)!}.$$

Comment: Good! Direct and non-spurious!

Comment: Nice edit too, more reader-friendly.

Comment: No, I thank you :) By the way, for other browsers' convenience, would you please somewhat develop your observation?

Comment: Hope everyone be happy in mathematics.